# axios content type not showing in request

Tags: node.js, request, axios, fetch

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'http://',
  'headers': {
  },
  form: {
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

transforming this to axios request:

```
let data = qs.stringify({   'username': '',
'password': '' })
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',data,
        headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},        
        url: '',
      };

      response[0] = await Axios(options).then((res) => {
      console.log("res",res)
      return res.data
    }
    ).catch((err) => {
      console.log("err status", err.response.status)
      return err.response.data
    });
```

gives an error and the headers shown doesnt have the url encoded:

```
   url: '',
    method: 'post',
    data: 'username=&password=',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
    },
```

Why the content-type : url-encoded is not in the headers and only the Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing which error you are receiving but the way you are setting the Axios call seems right following the Axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format). So I suspect it is a problem on how you have set up your Node.js server.

If you are using Express.js v.4+, probably you forgot to set up in your server the directive to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type as explained [here](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.body) in the official documentation.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

If you are using the `body-parser` package you need to set up your server with:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: The first request that is working (var request = require('request');), is that a url-encoded request ??

Comment: [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is a HTTP client that supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type out of the box. If the previous call was working before properly in your server then you might have a problem of defaults setting in the Axios HTTP client. Check if you are using interceptor in any way.